# PHP, how to rewrite/change only 1 line in external txt file

Tags: php

First of all I know that there was topic about this, but I couldn't understand it so that I could use it in this case.

**HTML: (Cannot be changed!)**

```
<form action="index.php" method="get">
    Select voting number:
    <select name="candidate">
        <option value=1 selected>1</option>
        <option value=2>2</option>
        <option value=3>3</option>
        <option value=4>4</option>
        <option value=5>5</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**student.txt:**

```
1|0
2|0
3|0
4|0
5|0
```

So the task is that, when user give number (1,2,3,4 or 5), that should change the line in txt file in that number line.

Example: user give value 2 ---> txt file should look like this:

```
1|0
2|1
3|0
4|0
5|0
```

next user give value 5:

```
1|0
2|1
3|0
4|0
5|1
```

and so on...

Also index.php should show total number of votes that txt file has including latest vote that user gave.

Comment: Even if you can rewrite that character, think of what will happen when the count jumps from 9 to 10? You certainly have to rewrite the file.

Comment: Hi, please mention what have you tried, have your written any code? do you have any idea how to approach this?

Comment: Why not save information as some ease-to-parse format like JSON? Then simply `file_put_contents('some.json', json_encode($newValues));`?

Comment: Looks like a school assignment

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of external tools (sed etc in Linux) that you call from PHP, or finding the location in the file, moving file pointer and write the bytes that have changed. Depending on the layout of the file it can become more fiddly though if you all of a sudden want to add new records in the middle of the file.

The easiest way is basically, load data from file, update data and write data to file again. Sure you might write "more bytes than needed" for a small update, but it will be very easy to do.

Comment: This is my school task, and our school has its own kinda tool which check the code, so I can't use anything like "external tools". Also I understand what should I do (
the procedure), but what I dont know is syntax to make it happen

Comment: That really isn't what Stackoverflow was intended for. You can ask about help with specific concepts etc. But, according to the rules, you should not ask people to debug your code or solve assignments for you. And trust me, you will learn way more if you get general help and try to solve your assignments yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$userInput = $_GET['candidate'];
$rows = explode(PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('votes.txt'));// Read file content and convert it into array
foreach($rows as $k => $v) {
    $row = explode('|', $v);
    if($userInput === $row[0]) {
        $newTotal = (int)$row[1] + 1;
        $rows[$k] = $row[0] . '|' . $newTotal;

        $rows = implode(PHP_EOL, $rows);// Convert array to string again
        file_put_contents('votes.txt', $rows);// Save changes
        break;
    }
}
```

I wouldn't have posted this answer, but I know sometimes schools give assignment and explain nothing. Don't just copy-paste this answer, try to understand the code. Please.